# Multiple galleries in Lightgallery hash plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, lightgallery

I cannot run the plugin Lightgallery hash. My wish is to have two galleries on the same page and clicking on a button should display the other. If I'm not mistaken the plugin should do this.

I added this HTML structure:

```
<div id="hash">
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-1.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-1.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-2.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-2.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-3.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-3.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-4.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-4.jpg" />
</a>
```

```
<div id="hash2">   
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-1.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-1.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-2.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-2.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-3.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-3.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-4.jpg">
    <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-4.jpg" />
</a>
```

And this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#hash").lightGallery({
                download: false,
                counter: false,
                hash: true;
                galleryId: 1
                });
            $("#hash2").lightGallery({
                download: false,
                counter: false,
                hash: true;
                galleryId: 2
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

Is this correct or is something wrong?

Comment: what is the issue? seems to be correct to me. make sure you have all the libraries loaded before this script.

Comment: The problem is that I appear the two galleries one above the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hash").lightGallery({
            download: false,
            counter: false,
            hash: true,  /*Here is the error.*/
            galleryId: 1
            });
        $("#hash2").lightGallery({
            download: false,
            counter: false,
            hash: true,/*Here is the error.*/
            galleryId: 2
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't just provide the code to solve the problem. Also provide a little explanation of why it solves the problem and how.

Comment: I just removed the " ; " and added " , " to separate parameters in the function.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should identify your gallery by a class, rather than id.

```html
<div class="lightgallery">
    <a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-1.jpg">
        <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-2.jpg">
        <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-2.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="lightgallery">   
    <a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-1.jpg">
        <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="img/img_port/reportage/img-2.jpg">
        <img src="img/img_port/reportage/thumb-2.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Then loop each with specific class and initiate lightGallery()

```js
$('.lightgallery').each(function (index) {
    $('#' + this.id).lightGallery({
        share: false,
        galleryId: index
    });
})
```